# Issues with jar creation using ant build file

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build, jar

At my WORK PLACE , I have an Eclipse Java project that is to be exported as a JAR Using build.xml file.

The jar is successfully being written out to the hard disk , but I find that in order to make it work , I have to extract all the contents of the jar to the folder where the jar is located  , and then double click it to make it run.

Ex :

Location of Jar : C:\MyTestFolder\App.jar

I have to unzip all contents to C:\MyTestFolder and then double click on the JAR to make it run successfully.

Otherwise , on directly double clicking the jar , nothing happens.

When I invoke the jar from command prompt , I recieve the following error :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger


        at application.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:49)
        at application.MainView$1.run(MainView.java:65)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        ... 14 more
```

This error exists despite having log4j on the classpath ( inside MANIFEST.MF file).
I'd like to learn of a resolution for the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like log4j.jar is not your classpath

Comment: @sidshu It already is.

Comment: It has be mentioned in the manifest file to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the jar is not able to find the dependent jars in the classpath.

You need to add the path of all the dependent jar file in the main jar's Manifest file.

After that you will be able to run the jar file without extracting the content.